# Node JS: Function Retry with Status Code 503

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

Given the following code, this Node JS API caller is communicating with a PHP-based API service.

After numerous testing, we found that every other or every-every other hit to the API endpoints cause a 503 status code.

Can any Node JS experts give some input or information on a good way to retry a function with a 503 code?

```
const https = require('https');

var apiCall = function(url, callback) {
    var apiUrl = {
        host: 'abc.com',
        path: '/' + url,
        headers: {
            'X': 'Y'
        }
    };
    https.get(apiUrl, function (res) {
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(data) {
            body += data;
        });
        res.on('end', function() {
            if (res.statusCode !== 200 && res.statusCode !== 201) {
                console.log('we shouldnt be in here if status is 200');
                console.log('status is: ' + res.statusCode);
                console.log('the end point we want to hit is: ' + url);
                callback({ reason: 'the api did not respond OK 200', data: { head: res.headers, statusMessage: res.statusMessage } }, null);
                return;
            }
            var rateLimitRemaining = res.headers['x-ratelimit-remaining'];
            if (rateLimitRemaining > 0) {
                console.log("Calls Left: " + rateLimitRemaining);
                callback(null, JSON.parse(body));
            } else {
                callback({ reason: 'we are out of API calls', data: res }, null);
            }
        });
    }).on('error', function(error) {
        callback({ reason: 'there is an error with the api', data: error }, null);
    });
};

module.exports = apiCall;
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTTP Error 503 - Service unavailable**

Description :

> The Web server (running the Web site) is currently unable to handle
>   the HTTP request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the
>   server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition which
>   will be alleviated after some delay. Some servers in this state may
>   also simply refuse the socket connection, in which case a different
>   error may be generated because the socket creation timed out.

Fixing 503 errors:

> The Web server is effectively 'closed for repair'. It is still
>   functioning minimally because it can, at least, respond with a 503
>   status code but full service is impossible i.e. the Web site is
>   simply unavailable. There are myriad possible reasons for this, but
>   generally it is because of some human intervention by the operators of
>   the Web server machine. You can usually expect that someone is working
>   on the problem, and normal service will resume as soon as possible.

***If you believe that you are hitting proper API with proper parameters*** then please contact the system operators of the Web site (e.g. your ISP) to determine why the service is down. They will be in a much better position to help you than we are for this type of error.

**Do a dummy test run of your code with other public APIs available on the net**.